# How to "Hello World" with maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, mojo

I'm doing a Mojo "Hello World" with the plugin maven:

```
package sample.plugin;

/*
 * Copyright 2001-2005 The Apache Software Foundation.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.ResolutionScope;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Goal which touches a timestamp file.
 *
 *
 */
@Mojo( name = "touch", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_SOURCES )
public class MyMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    /**
     * Location of the file.
     */
    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}", property = "outputDir", required = true )
    private File outputDirectory;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info("Hello World!!!");
        File f = outputDirectory;

        if ( !f.exists() )
        {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        File touch = new File( f, "touch.txt" );

        FileWriter w = null;
        try
        {
            w = new FileWriter( touch );

            w.write( "touch.txt" );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new MojoExecutionException( "Error creating file " + touch, e );
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( w != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    w.close();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <name>hello-maven-plugin Maven Plugin</name>

    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>hello-maven-plugin</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>help-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-plugin-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>run-its</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                            <pomIncludes>
                                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                            </pomIncludes>
                            <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
                            <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
                            <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>integration-test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

when I do a "mvn install" by the eclipse he builds the application normally, but not display the terminal log message as the links [avajava](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-hello-world-goal-for-a-maven-plugin.html?page=1) and [maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

Because it does not display any messages? And where the maven is creating the touch file? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you create a POM file that calls for your plugin?

Comment: Hello bmargulies, I would like to know how to display the "Hello World" on the console and how do I find the touch file in the sample code. I edited my question and enter the pom.xml file.

Comment: That is the pom that builds your plugin. To run it, you need _another_ pom that uses it. Typically this would be in an integration test. I recommend that you read the source of one of the many standard plugins.

Comment: bmargulies u have some source to indicate me? For not even know how to search in Google on this issue.

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-assembly-plugin for example.